# how can I use IntelliJ live edit with django templates?

Tags: django, google-chrome, django-templates, google-chrome-devtools

I like the IntelliJ 'live edit' feature but it doesn't work for Django templates because obviously they are just a bunch of variables and its not finding the CSS files. Is there some way of working 'live' on Django templates? (or any other templating system for that matter).

Similarly I tried to use Chrome devtools autosave but it also didn't work, presumably it wants me to open an html file locally (i.e. file://).

And using chrome inspector to edit stuff is a pain because you have to copy and paste your changes - unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using IntelliJ 12.0.4 Ultimate with the Python plugin (this is more or less equivalent to PyCharm) to work on Django templates. It doesn't look like the Live Edit functionality works as per usual, indeed because the template has to be rendered to HTML first by Django.

One alternative is to assign a keyboard shortcut to the "View | Reload in Browser" menu item.

Another alternative is to use a Chrome plugin such as [ChromeReload](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromereload/njoipeaphfnaplplihpbgndfojhdhmjo?hl=en): You can set this to reload a specific page at a specific interval.